# Firemonkey iOS TExpanderButton onclick

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

I am trying to add custom behavior to a TExpander.  Basically what I am trying to acheive is the following:
I've got multiple TExpanders on my form.  When the user expands one of these TExpanders, all the other TExpanders should be minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to handle the OnResize event for the TExpander, and then in that event, check the IsExpanded property of each of the other TExpander panels and set them to False.